# Mapstruct FilerException after upgrading IntelliJ Idea 2023.1.3

Tags: intellij-idea, mapstruct

I'm having this error when I perform any maven goal from the IntelliJ after upgrading to 2023.1.3:

```
java: Internal error in the mapping processor: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
javax.annotation.processing.FilerException: Attempt to recreate a file for
type com.example.mapper.PersonMapperImpl
at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MapperRenderingProcessor.createSourceFile(MapperRenderingProcessor.java:59)
```

Is there any way to fix it?

Something similar already happened on [other upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65112406/intellij-idea-mapstruct-java-internal-error-in-the-mapping-processor-java-lang). But this doesn't work this time

Comment: Check the following similar cases 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73223385/problem-with-internal-error-in-the-mapping-procesor-while-using-mapstruct and https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2802
 
Otherwise, reach out to **Help | Contact Support** to create a direct request for the support team.